# Что такое глупая сортировка?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что такое *глупая сортировка*. Википедия не даёт однозначного ответа на этот вопрос. Поиск по словам *глупая сортировка* и *stupid sort* дают совершенно разные результаты.

Что же такое глупая сортировка?

Можно ли привести в качестве примера реализацию глупой сортировки на C#?

Comment: Уточни вопрос, какую именно из "глупых" сортировок ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: Эй, минусаторы, не забивайте нормальный в принципе вопрос, лучше почитайте ответ!

Comment: @IgorChubin: Часть про C# теперь явно лишняя. Учитывая, что от вопроса Дмитрия ничего не осталось, да, стоит переоткрыть ;-)

Answer (score 27):

*Глупая сортировка* это вполне законный термин, использующийся для обозначения некоторых алгоритмов сортировки. Путаница возникает потому, что им обозначают несколько различных алгоритмов, ничего общего между собой не имеющих. Давайте разберёмся, что имеют в виду, когда используют этот термин.

Есть как минимум два алгоритма сортировки, которые обычно называются глупой сортировкой.
Это *gnome sort* и *bogosort*. Рассмотрим оба из них, отсортировав их в порядке увеличения глупости.

**Gnome sort**

Я так полагаю, что речь в вашем вопросе идёт, вероятнее, о *гномьей сортировке* (*gnome sort*).

Описание алгоритма в двух словах (сделанное голландским учёным Диком Груном, благодаря которому алгоритм и получил своё название):

> Гномья сортировка основана на технике, используемой обычным
>   голландским садовым гномом (нидерл. tuinkabouter). Это метод, которым
>   садовый гном сортирует линию цветочных горшков. По существу он смотрит
>   на следующий и предыдущий садовые горшки: если они в правильном
>   порядке, он шагает на один горшок вперёд, иначе он меняет их местами и
>   шагает на один горшок назад. Граничные условия: если нет предыдущего
>   горшка, он шагает вперёд; если нет следующего горшка, он закончил.

То есть алгоритм очень простой: берём число, идём назад и смотрим, больше оно или меньше, и если меньше, меняем всё время пока число не станет "на своё место". Потом берём следующее число и так далее (действительно, — ну а что вы хотели от садового гнома — глупее уже сложно сортировать, но как вы увидите чуть позже, это возможно).

[image: Визуализация рыботы алгоритма гномьей сортировки]

*Визуализация работы алгоритма гномьей сортировки, Источник: Википедия*

В этом случае на C# это будет выглядеть так:

```
public static void gnomeSort(ref int[] a)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;

    while (i < a.Length)
    {
        if (a[i - 1] <= a[i])
        {
            i = j;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            int tmp = a[i - 1];
            a[i - 1] = a[i];
            a[i] = tmp;
            i -= 1;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                i = 1;
                j = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я думаю, то как работает в данном случае сортировка, очевидно, но если нужно, я прокомментирую и объясню.

Подробности об этом методе сортировки:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort (англ.)
- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гномья_сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (рус.)

**Bogosort**

Теперь, расскажу о втором методе сортировки, который также часто называют глупой сортировкой (хотя, как по мне, то правильнее было бы назвать эту сортировку не глупой, а *сортировкой для полных дебилов*). Это *bogosort*.

Суть метода заключается в том, что вы перемешиваете все значения в массиве 
случайным образом в надежде, что у вас все значения выстроятся в отсортированном порядке (как вы сами понимаете, с таким же успехом можно тасовать колоду карт, пока все карты не выстроятся по мастям и значению; или читать `/dev/random`, пока биты не выстроятся в пиратскую копию винды).

На псевдокоде это будет выглядеть так:

```
while not массив_отсортирован?(массив) {
  перемешать(массив);
}
```

Перемешать массив на C# можно следующим образом:

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

(как проверить, отсортирован ли массив, то есть реализацию функции `массив_отсортирован?` писать не буду, оставляю вам в качестве самостоятельного задания).

Алгоритмическая сложность данного метода в среднем составляет O((n+1)!),
в худшем случае, как вы понимаете, сложно не ограничена, потому что вам может просто не везти, и числа упорно не будут случайно сортироваться в правильном порядке.

Подробнее об этом чуде инженерной мысли вы можете прочитать здесь:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort (англ.)
- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort (рус.)

**PS. Bogobogosort: Глупой, ещё глупее**

Конечно, только потому что эти алгоритмы называются глупыми, не стоит думать, что в них пик глупости достигнут, и ничего более неэффективного придумать невозможно (хотя Bogosort ставит действительно высокую планку).

Как совершенно справедливо замечает *VladD* (спасибо за очень ценное замечение!), нет пределов человеческой глупости, а следовательно нет пределов и глупости глупых сортировок.

Примером следующего milestone на этом пути может по праву считаться *Bogobogosort*, по сравнению с которой Bogosort с её O((n+1)!) это просто верх алгоритмической эффективности.

У Bogobogosort получилось довести эффективность до O(n!^n!).

Подробнее:

- [Bogobogosort](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/bogobogosort.html) (англ.)

Comment: Вот же есть: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Всегда можно придумать алгоритм ещё глупее. Например, [Bogobogosort](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/bogobogosort.html).

Comment: @VladD: это авторы статьи сами решили, что это глупая сортировка; понятно, что сортировку описанную в их статье служно назвать умной, но к классической *stupid sort* она отношения не имеет. Лучше ту статью вообще переписать

Comment: @VladD: Нигде и не утверждается, что пик глупости достигнут, это же сортировка *глупая*, а не *глупейшая*

Comment: Думаю, любой алгоритм сортировки _можно_ сделать на порядок медленнее таким вот образом. (Впрочем, не уверен на все 100%.)

Comment: @VladD: Влад, спасибо большое за наводку про Bogobogosort

Comment: @VladD: Модифицировал статью на русской википедии, на которую вы ссылаетесь, немного описав проблематику и поставив ссылку на наше обсуждение здесь

Comment: `MyArray.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next)` - не похоже на c# :)

Comment: @Grundy: согласен, задумался и написал на VBA вместо C# почему-то. Переписал на C#

Comment: можно было просто лямбду на c# поменять, но так тоже норм

Comment: @IgorChubin, в VBA есть лямбды? Это ж вроде VB.NET?